# Cast JSON object to interface ignoring case sensitivity in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to "convert" a jsonObj to some interface when the json has some members that differs from the interface's members only by case sensitivity?

```
interface Desire {
    propTest1: string,
    propTest2: string
}
    
let jsonFromApi = {
    PropTest1: "aa",
    PropTest2: "bb"
}
let result = smartCast<Desire>(jsonFromApi); 
    
console.log(results)

// I expect {
    propTest1: "aa",
    propTest2: "bb"
}
```

**And here's what I've tried so far:**

```
function smartCast<T>(from: object): T{

    type LOWERCASE = { [p in keyof T & string as Lowercase<`${p}`>]: T[p] }
    type LOWERCASE_MAP = { [p in keyof T & string as Lowercase<`${p}`>]: p }

    const lowerCase = Object.entries(from).reduce((a: any, [key, val]) => {
        a[key.toLowerCase()] = val;
        return a;
    }, {}) as LOWERCASE;

    console.log("lowercase ", lowerCase)

    const lowerCaseMap = Object.entries(lowerCase).reduce((a: any, [key, val]) => {
        a[key] = key;// how to get something like LOWERCASE_MAP[key] ?? typescript === runtime without types :(((
        return a;
    }, {});    
    
    return Object.entries(lowerCase).reduce((a: any, [key, val]) => {
        a[lowerCaseMap[key]] = val
    }, {}) as T;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the casing of properties of a JSON object you get from an API at runtime. But where are the typescript definitions for the objects originally coming from? Parsing JSON will usually give you `any` type in design time, unless you use an API library that already returns typed objects.

If you don't have type definitions or you are going to manually recreate them anyway, just set the return type of your case modifying function to this type. You don't need to use typescript's generics for that:

```
type AnyObject = {[index: string]: unknown};

interface DesiredResultObject {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

const jsonObject = {
    Prop1: "answer",
    Prop2: 42,
}

function toLowerCaseProps(obj: AnyObject): DesiredResultObject {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
        a[key.toLowerCase()] = val;
        return a;
    }, {} as AnyObject) as unknown as DesiredResultObject;
}

const result = toLowerCaseProps(jsonObject);
```

If you already have type definitions for the API objects and you want to transform their keys but don't want to create the new typing manually, you can do something like this:

```
type AnyObject = {[index: string]: unknown};

type LowerCaseProps<T extends AnyObject> = {
    [K in keyof T as Lowercase<string & K>]: T[K]
};

const jsonObject = {
    Prop1: "answer",
    Prop2: 42
}

function toLowerCaseProps<T extends AnyObject>(obj: T): LowerCaseProps<T> {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
        a[key.toLowerCase()] = val;
        return a;
    }, {} as AnyObject) as LowerCaseProps<T>;
}

const result = toLowerCaseProps(jsonObject);

console.log(result.prop1); // outputs "answer"
// console.log(result.Prop1); // this won't compile
console.log(result.prop2); // outputs 42
// console.log(result.Prop2); // this won't compile
```

Comment: The API definition is auto-generated based on backed exposed API, but the generator applies camelCase naming standard, as per typescript recommandations. The problem is the Backed(C#) expose it's API using PascalCase (uppercasing first letter). I already applied your first solution, but I wanted a more generic solution, not to rely on the fact that the API is generated using camelCase naming convention.